# NameError: name '_predicted' is not defined, while using google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, knn

I am learning K-NEAREST NEIGHBORS (KNN).I can run the code in Jupyter Notebook.But I get the error "NameError: name '_predicted' is not defined, while using google colab.

I learn from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngLyX54e1LU&list=PLqnslRFeH2Upcrywf-u2etjdxxkL8nl7E&index=1

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cmap = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'])

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1234)

import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks')
from knn import KNN
clf = KNN(k=3)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
acc = np.sum(predictions == y_test) / len(y_test)
print(acc)
```

knn.py

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def euclidiean_distance(x1, x2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((x1-x2)**2))

class KNN:

    def __init__(self, k=3):
        self.k = k
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.X_train = X
        self.y_train = y

    def predict(self, X):
        predicted_labels = [self._predicted(x) for x in X]
        return np.array(predicted_labels)
    
    def _predicted(self, x):
        distance = [euclidiean_distance(x, x_train) for x_train in self.X_train]
        k_indices = np.argsort(distance)[:self.k]
        k_nearest_laybels = [self.y_train[i] for i in k_indices]
        most_common = Counter(k_nearest_laybels).most_common(1)
        return most_common[0][0]
```

Comment: Hi, I tested your code on Colab and it worked fine.

Comment: I open the new notebook, and it worked fine.

Comment: I edited knn.py. But I forgot to clear cell output.